# Reset Semantic UI Dropdowns Firing onChange Callback/Event-handler

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui, jquery-callback, eventhandler

I'm using the [Semantic UI Dropdown](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) and I have a bit of trouble with resetting the dropdown back to the page-load state. Basically resetting the selection.

I tried 2 different approaches but both don't really give me what I'm looking for *(I also have 2 different types of dropdowns - the plain old selection type and the searchable type where it filters out the options based on what you type in the input)*.

#### Approaches

1. `$(".ui.dropdown").dropdown("restore defaults");`
2. `$(".ui.dropdown").dropdown("clear");`

A common problem I get from either approach is that it fires the `onChange` callback/event-handler of the dropdowns - where I make an AJAX call. I would like to reset the dropdowns **without** invoking the `onChange` callback/event-handler.

Another problem that is common from either approach is that for dropdowns where I can search for an option - if I search for something that doesn't exist in the options and get a `No results found.` and click on that option then afterwards initiate either approaches it won't clear it. The search text just stays there and the options remain filtered.

A specific problem I experience when using `"clear"` is that for dropdowns where you can't search (the basic selection type) it literally clears it and so nothing is selected even though the dropdown defaults to the first option.

---

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3xg0ux1/4/) I prepared for you to see my problem.

#### HTML

```
<select name="firstname" class="search ui dropdown">
  <option value="">Firstname</option>
  <option value="1">Ahmed</option>
  <option value="2">Brodie</option>
  <option value="3">Cameron</option>
  <option value="4">Doug</option>
  <option value="5">Ely</option>
  <option value="6">Fionna</option>
</select>

<select name="gender" class="no-search ui dropdown">
  <option value="0">Male</option>
  <option value="1">Female</option>
</select>

<button>
  <span>Reset</span>
</button>
```

#### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".search.ui.dropdown").dropdown({
    allowAdditions: false,
    fullTextSearch: true,
    sortSelect: true,
    onChange: function(value, text, choice) {
        alert("FIRST NAME - on change event fired - Run some AJAX.");
    }
  });

  $(".no-search.ui.dropdown").dropdown({
    allowAdditions: false,
    sortSelect: true,
    onChange: function(value, text, choice) {
        alert("GENDER - on change event fired - Run some AJAX.");
    }
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    // $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown("clear");
    $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown("restore defaults");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a more verbose and structured html with hidden inputs instead of oldschool selects:

```
  <div class="no-search ui selection dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="gender" />
    <div class="text">Male</div>  <!-- Selection by default -->
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="active item" data-value="0" data-text="Male">
        Male
      </div>
      <div class="item" data-value="1" data-text="Female">
        Female
      </div>
    </div>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  </div>
```

Note that you may specify a *default selection* with `<div class="text">`, or a *placeholder* - with `<div class="default text">`.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akhanov/xvpxpbgr/2/) for a complete example.

As for ajax calls, you may check if you have some value in `onChange` handler - it will be null on 'restore defaults':

```
onChange: function(value, text, choice) {
  if (typeof value !== "undefined") {
    // ajax call
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with `if(typeof value !== "undefined")`.

Comment: You're right, it's a better way since you may have defined falsy values like `0` too.